# Rodar funções personalizadas no console do browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão, firebug, userscripts

É um pouco cansativo ter que ficar escrevendo `console.log()` toda hora. Sei que no meu código posso definir a função `log` que faz exatamente isso. Mas fora do ambiente do aplicativo, gostaria de ter isso sempre disponível no browser, sendo que é só abrir o console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> e digitar `log('alou')`.

Por exemplo, a extensão [Nice Alert](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nice-alert/ehnbelnegmgdnjaghgomaakjcmpcakhk) do Chrome substitui completamente o `alert()` do JavaScript. Minha intenção não é subsituir funções padrão, mas como fazer algo semelhante?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que o Nice Alert faz é basicamente:

```
var w = window;
if (!w.alert.is_nice) {
    w.alert = function alert(msg) {/*etc*}
}
```

Seguem uma solução como extensão do navegador e como Userscript. Uma extensão tem mais permissões e roda em todo lugar. Usado como Userscript funciona em muitos sites, porém não outros (como Github), mas não sei exatamente porquê.

---

Para fazer uma extensão personalizada no Chrome ou Opera, estes seriam os arquivos:

#### `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "(SOPT) Console functions",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["console.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }]
}
```

#### `console.js`

<sup>Atenção para o uso do objeto [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) que as funções recebem.</sup>

```
function main() {
    var w = window;
    if (!w.log) {
        w.log = function log() {
            for( var i=0; i<arguments.length;i++)
            console.log( arguments[i] );
        }
    }
}

if (!document.xmlVersion) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+ main +')();'));
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}
```

---

Também pode-se usar um [Usercript que roda em Chrome e Firefox](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2049/como-modificar-o-site-sem-ter-que-pedir-um-novo-recurso/2085#2085), é só colar o seguinte cabeçalho seguido do código `console.js` acima:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       (SOPT) Console functions
// @namespace  userscripts.pt.stackoverflow.com
// @version    0.1
// @match      http*://*/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

---

**Resultado**:

[image: log personalizado]

**Referências**:

- <sup>[adding custom functionality into chrome's console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051533/1287812)</sup>
- <sup>[Injecting JS functions into the page from a Greasemonkey script on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2303147/1287812)</sup>